# Create time Series Object from Wide Data, group by column value

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression

Below is my dataframe (my_df). I am trying to make it time series object to predict for year 2020 but I am struggling to convert this format of data.

I am trying to use below code to convert it into timeseries but I get NA in location & data is not in timeseries format

My attempt

```
ts(my_df[,c(-2,-3)], start=c(2009), end=c(2014), frequency=1)
```

Dataframe my_df below

```
structure(list(`Geogrphical Location` = c("United States", "Northeast", 
"Midwest", "South", "West", ".Alabama", ".Alaska", ".Arizona", 
".Arkansas", ".California", ".Colorado", ".Connecticut", ".Delaware", 
".District of Columbia", ".Florida", ".Georgia", ".Hawaii", ".Idaho", 
".Illinois", ".Indiana", ".Iowa", ".Kansas", ".Kentucky", ".Louisiana", 
".Maine", ".Maryland", ".Massachusetts", ".Michigan", ".Minnesota", 
".Mississippi", ".Missouri", ".Montana", ".Nebraska", ".Nevada", 
".New Hampshire", ".New Jersey", ".New Mexico", ".New York", 
".North Carolina", ".North Dakota", ".Ohio", ".Oklahoma", ".Oregon", 
".Pennsylvania", ".Rhode Island", ".South Carolina", ".South Dakota", 
".Tennessee", ".Texas", ".Utah", ".Vermont", ".Virginia", ".Washington", 
".West Virginia", ".Wisconsin", ".Wyoming", "Puerto Rico"), Census = c(308745538, 
55317240, 66927001, 114555744, 71945553, 4779736, 710231, 6392017, 
2915918, 37253956, 5029196, 3574097, 897934, 601723, 18801310, 
9687653, 1360301, 1567582, 12830632, 6483802, 3046355, 2853118, 
4339367, 4533372, 1328361, 5773552, 6547629, 9883640, 5303925, 
2967297, 5988927, 989415, 1826341, 2700551, 1316470, 8791894, 
2059179, 19378102, 9535483, 672591, 11536504, 3751351, 3831074, 
12702379, 1052567, 4625364, 814180, 6346105, 25145561, 2763885, 
625741, 8001024, 6724540, 1852994, 5686986, 563626, 3725789), 
    `Estimates Base` = c(308758105, 55318353, 66929825, 114563005, 
    71946922, 4780131, 710249, 6392301, 2916025, 37254522, 5029324, 
    3574114, 897936, 601766, 18804592, 9688680, 1360301, 1567650, 
    12831574, 6484136, 3046869, 2853129, 4339344, 4533479, 1328364, 
    5773786, 6547813, 9884129, 5303924, 2968103, 5988928, 989414, 
    1826334, 2700691, 1316461, 8791953, 2059198, 19378110, 9535688, 
    672591, 11536727, 3751615, 3831072, 12702857, 1052940, 4625410, 
    814195, 6346298, 25146100, 2763888, 625741, 8001041, 6724545, 
    1853011, 5687289, 563767, 3726157), `2010` = c(309348193, 
    55388056, 66978602, 114863114, 72118421, 4785492, 714031, 
    6408312, 2921995, 37332685, 5048644, 3579899, 899816, 605183, 
    18849098, 9713521, 1363945, 1571010, 12841578, 6490528, 3050738, 
    2858850, 4348662, 4544996, 1327730, 5788584, 6565524, 9877495, 
    5311147, 2970322, 5996118, 990641, 1830051, 2703284, 1316872, 
    8803729, 2064756, 19402640, 9558915, 674526, 11540983, 3759603, 
    3838048, 12712343, 1053337, 4635943, 816325, 6356671, 25244310, 
    2775326, 625982, 8025773, 6743226, 1854230, 5690263, 564513, 
    3721525), `2011` = c(311663358, 55632766, 67153331, 116061801, 
    72815460, 4799918, 722713, 6467163, 2939493, 37676861, 5118360, 
    3589893, 907924, 620477, 19096952, 9811610, 1377864, 1584143, 
    12860012, 6516480, 3065223, 2869503, 4369354, 4575404, 1328231, 
    5843603, 6611923, 9876213, 5348562, 2978162, 6010717, 997821, 
    1842283, 2718379, 1318473, 8841243, 2077756, 19519529, 9650963, 
    685476, 11544824, 3786274, 3868031, 12744293, 1052451, 4672637, 
    824398, 6397634, 25646389, 2816124, 626730, 8110035, 6822520, 
    1854972, 5709640, 567725, 3678732), `2012` = c(313998379, 
    55829059, 67332320, 117299171, 73537829, 4815960, 731089, 
    6549634, 2950685, 38011074, 5189867, 3593795, 916993, 635327, 
    19344156, 9914668, 1391820, 1595911, 12870798, 6537743, 3076310, 
    2885262, 4384799, 4603429, 1328895, 5889651, 6658008, 9887238, 
    5380285, 2984945, 6025415, 1005196, 1855725, 2752565, 1321182, 
    8873211, 2083784, 19602769, 9746175, 702087, 11550839, 3817054, 
    3899116, 12771854, 1052901, 4720760, 834441, 6454306, 26071655, 
    2855782, 626444, 8192048, 6895226, 1856560, 5726177, 576765, 
    3634488), `2013` = c(316204908, 55988771, 67543948, 118424320, 
    74247869, 4829479, 736879, 6624617, 2958663, 38335203, 5267603, 
    3596003, 925395, 649165, 19582022, 9984938, 1406481, 1612011, 
    12879505, 6569102, 3091930, 2892821, 4400477, 4626402, 1329076, 
    5931129, 6706786, 9898982, 5418521, 2990482, 6042711, 1014314, 
    1868559, 2786464, 1322687, 8899162, 2085193, 19673546, 9841590, 
    724019, 11570022, 3852415, 3925751, 12781338, 1053033, 4767894, 
    844922, 6494821, 26473525, 2902663, 627140, 8262692, 6968006, 
    1853231, 5742854, 582684, 3593077), `2014` = c(318563456, 
    56116791, 67726368, 119696311, 75023986, 4843214, 736705, 
    6719993, 2966912, 38680810, 5349648, 3591873, 934948, 659005, 
    19888741, 10087231, 1416349, 1633532, 12867544, 6595233, 
    3108030, 2899360, 4413057, 4647880, 1330719, 5967295, 6749911, 
    9915767, 5453109, 2992400, 6060930, 1022867, 1881145, 2833013, 
    1328743, 8925001, 2083024, 19718515, 9934399, 739904, 11594408, 
    3877499, 3968371, 12790565, 1054480, 4828430, 852561, 6544663, 
    26944751, 2941836, 626984, 8317372, 7054196, 1848514, 5758377, 
    583642, 3534874), `2015` = c(320896618, 56184737, 67838387, 
    121039206, 75834288, 4853875, 737709, 6817565, 2977853, 38993940, 
    5448819, 3584730, 944076, 670377, 20244914, 10199398, 1425157, 
    1652828, 12839047, 6612768, 3121997, 2906721, 4424611, 4668960, 
    1329453, 5994983, 6784240, 9917715, 5482435, 2989390, 6076204, 
    1032073, 1893765, 2883758, 1330111, 8935421, 2080328, 19747183, 
    10035186, 756835, 11605090, 3907414, 4024634, 12791904, 1055607, 
    4894834, 857919, 6595056, 27429639, 2990632, 626088, 8367587, 
    7160290, 1841053, 5767891, 586555, 3473181), `2016` = c(323127513, 
    56209510, 67941429, 122319574, 76657000, 4863300, 741894, 
    6931071, 2988248, 39250017, 5540545, 3576452, 952065, 681170, 
    20612439, 10310371, 1428557, 1683140, 12801539, 6633053, 
    3134693, 2907289, 4436974, 4681666, 1331479, 6016447, 6811779, 
    9928300, 5519952, 2988726, 6093000, 1042520, 1907116, 2940058, 
    1334795, 8944469, 2081015, 19745289, 10146788, 757952, 11614373, 
    3923561, 4093465, 12784227, 1056426, 4961119, 865454, 6651194, 
    27862596, 3051217, 624594, 8411808, 7288000, 1831102, 5778708, 
    585501, 3411307)), row.names = c(NA, -57L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Please help to let me build a time series object so that I can use linear regression then to predict for year 2020 for any state mentioned in column1

Answer (score 1):

The `tsibble` package is designed to make this easy.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
my_ts <- my_df %>% 
  rename(Location = "Geogrphical Location") %>%
  select(Location, `2010`:`2016`) %>%
  gather(key="Year", value="value", `2010`:`2016`) %>%
  mutate(
    Year = as.numeric(Year),
    Location = gsub("\\.", "", Location)
  ) %>%
  as_tsibble(index=Year, key=id(Location)) %>%
  as.ts()
```

Most of this is just tidyverse code putting the data in long form, and cleaning up the variable names and location values. The `as_tsibble()` line does most of the work in setting it up as a multivariate time series, and then `as.ts()` makes it into a `ts` object.

```
my_ts
#> Time Series:
#> Start = 2010 
#> End = 2016 
#> Frequency = 1 
#>      Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas California Colorado Connecticut
#> 2010 4785492 714031 6408312  2921995   37332685  5048644     3579899
#> 2011 4799918 722713 6467163  2939493   37676861  5118360     3589893
#> 2012 4815960 731089 6549634  2950685   38011074  5189867     3593795
#> 2013 4829479 736879 6624617  2958663   38335203  5267603     3596003
#> 2014 4843214 736705 6719993  2966912   38680810  5349648     3591873
#> 2015 4853875 737709 6817565  2977853   38993940  5448819     3584730
#> 2016 4863300 741894 6931071  2988248   39250017  5540545     3576452
```

Comment: This is perfect, can you just tell me how to add Linear regression to this, because I can't seem to get the formulat right, I use tslm(my_ts) (after subsetting only for Utah state)

Comment: fit <- tslm(my_ts[,'Utah'] ~ trend)

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert location variable into a factor. However, the locations are then in numeric format of the factors (labels are discarded).

```
df1$`Geogrphical Location` <- as.factor(df1$`Geogrphical Location`)

> ts(df1[, -(2:3)], start=c(2009), end=c(2014), frequency=1)
Time Series:
Start = 2009 
End = 2014 
Frequency = 1 
     Geogrphical Location      2010      2011      2012      2013      2014      2015      2016
2009                   56 309348193 311663358 313998379 316204908 318563456 320896618 323127513
2010                   53  55388056  55632766  55829059  55988771  56116791  56184737  56209510
2011                   52  66978602  67153331  67332320  67543948  67726368  67838387  67941429
2012                   55 114863114 116061801 117299171 118424320 119696311 121039206 122319574
2013                   57  72118421  72815460  73537829  74247869  75023986  75834288  76657000
2014                    1   4785492   4799918   4815960   4829479   4843214   4853875   4863300
```

A little "code-book" gives you this code:

```
data.frame(lbl=df1$`Geogrphical Location`, 
           num=as.numeric(df1$`Geogrphical Location`))
```

*Note:* It is better not to use spaces within variable names in R.

```
names(df1)[1] <- "Geographical.Location"
```

You can also get rid of the leading points.

```
df1$Geographical.Location <- gsub("\\.", "", df1$Geographical.Location)
```

Then do like above:

```
df1$Geographical.Location <- as.factor(df1$Geographical.Location)
```